# Fourier series of Piecewise -2pi to 2pi with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, fft, calculus, piecewise

I'm trying to find the fourier series of the following piecewise

```
f_t = sym.Piecewise(
    (sym.sin(t), (t >= -2 * sym.pi) & (t <= 2 * sym.pi))
)
```

This is the code I already have, but I'm not able to get some terms because it's stuck. Maybe there is another way to do the calculations and get some terms of the series?

```
import sympy as sym

t = sym.symbols('t', real = True)

#piecewise function
f_t = sym.Piecewise(
    (sym.sin(t), (t >= -2 * sym.pi) & (t <= 2 * sym.pi))
)

#3 terms
num_terms = 3
approx_fourier_series = sym.fourier_series(f_t, (t, -2 * sym.pi, 2 * sym.pi)).truncate(n=num_terms)

#result
print("Fourier Series with", num_terms, "terms:")
print(approx_fourier_series)
```

I've tried doing this code but I'm not able to get the terms because it seems stuck, so maybe there's another way to calculate the fourier series.